# What is "ctr" file extension?

Tags: programming-languages

What is "ctr" file extension?  Recently I found one site with a file named "create.ctr", what language is that?

Comment: What platform are you on? What webserver?

Comment: Careful ! The site has really poor stats on WOT. Netcraft says it's using apache on linux.

Comment: It doesn't "have to" mean anything. Most web servers will allow you to associate any extension with any scripting engine you like. So short of asking them, there's not much you can do (other than google, perhaps)

Answer (score 2):

File Extension .CTR Details

http://filext.com/file-extension/CTR

File extension CTR

http://www.file-extensions.org/ctr-file-extension

File Extension CTR and CTR File Format

http://www.computerfileextensions.com/file-extensions.php/CTR

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any resource about programming languages suggesting (or enforcing) a  [.ctr extension](http://filext.com/file-extension/CTR).

If the website you linked is using Apache, they may be using [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html) and `.ctr` might not mean anything.

You may have better luck with this question on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).